# Create Magento Multistore with subfloder Style without create subfolder inside Magento directory

Tags: magento

Is possible to create a Magento Multistore with a single domain and with 
a series of substores with urls like that:

domain/store1
domain/store2

Without create subfolder inside magento directory?

Comment: the domain is not dependent from magento directly, you will manage it with your host parameters. See with an admin system how to set up virtual hosts and it will be done in few seconds

Comment: Thank you for reply , can you give me more detail about Vhost configuration?

Comment: it depends on the server you have, but a simple look on google for "create vhost subdomain" will explain you how to do it for your server. If you still need help, post it on the appropriated section ( apache / nginx...) because it won't be magento dependent

Comment: Thanks for all the advice.